# preg_replace - don't replace in already replaced parts

Tags: php, preg-replace

Given SQL-query with placeholders:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`=? AND `b`=?
```

and query parameters ['aaa', 'bbb'], i would like to replace ?-placeholders with corresponding params. So, I do it like this:

```php
$sql = preg_replace(array_fill(0, count($params), '#\?#'), $params, $sql, 1);
```

(we do not concentrate on mysql-escaping, quoting etc. in this question).

Everything works fine and I get

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`=aaa AND `b`=bbb
```

But if our first parameter looks like this: "?aa", everything fails:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`=bbba AND `b`=?
```

obviously, first replacement pass changes "a=?" into "a=?aa", and second pass changes this (just inserted) question mark into "bbb".

The question is: how can I bypass this confusing preg_replace behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to use one item from `$params` at a time for each replacement.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`=? AND `b`=?';
var_dump('Original: ' . $sql);
$params=['aaa','bbb'];

$sql = preg_replace_callback("/\\?/",function($m) use (&$params) {
    return array_shift($params);
}, $sql);

var_dump('Result: ' . $sql);
```

Let me know

Comment: First of all, there should be an array of four "/\\?/" as the first argument to preg_replace_callback. And, second, the result is exactly like with preg_replace - it replaces "?" in "??a" )))

Comment: @DmitriyChetverikov, *there should be an array of four "/\\?/" as the first argument to preg_replace_callback* - no, read the docs of the function. *it replaces "?" in "??a"* - no, it doesn't. If you mean it replaces "?" WITH "??a", well of course, it is supposed to. take a look at my `$params` variable: its first item is '??a'. Try it with your `$params` variable and you'll see the result you expect. And no, it doesn't do the same as `preg_replace`. In any case, I just edited the answer with your original data, try it

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This solution works perfectly fine and is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @DmitriyChetverikov, glad it worked. just remember to mark the answer as the correct one, if it indeed is.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this with `preg_replace` or `str_replace`. I would use `preg_split` so empty returns can be removed (If `explode` had empty removal option I'd use that). For there iterate over the return and add in values. You also can quote the values with this. I presume the purpose of this is for debugging parameterized queries.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`=? AND `b`=?';
$v = array('1?1', "222");
$e = preg_split('/\?/', $sql, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$c = '';
foreach($e as $k => $v1){
    $c .= $v1 . "'" . $v[$k] ."'"; 
}
error_log($c);
```

Then your error log will have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `a`='1?1' AND `b`='222'
```

Comment: provided answer works for sure, but preg_replace would be elegant one-line solution. If it is not possible with preg_replace, will have to switch to explode (or preg_split)